# How to implement parent-child Recyclerview on Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

can you give me some reference about parent-child recycleview? i have successfully made `parent-Recycleview` but i'm stuck to pass `child-Recycleview` when im clicked item from `parent`

NB: i'm use dummy data

This is example of recyclerview I want to create:

[image: reference recyclerview]

and this is my code

RecycleParentAdapter.java

```
public class RecycleParentMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleParentMenuAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Store> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    public RecycleParentMenuAdapter(ArrayList<Store> mData, Context context) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = mInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_store_lists, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.storeName.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
//        holder.storeImage.setImageURI(mData.get(position).getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mData != null) ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private CircleImageView storeImage;
        private TextView storeName;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            storeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivListStoreImage);
            storeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvListStoreName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public int getItem(int id) {
        return (mData != null) ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

RecycleChildAdapter.java

```
public class RecycleChildMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleChildMenuAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//    private String[] mData;
    private ArrayList<Menu> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    public RecycleChildMenuAdapter(ArrayList<Menu> mData, Context context) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = mInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_menu_lists, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
//        viewHolder.myTextView.setText(mData.get(i).get);
//        viewHolder.id.setText((int) 12l);
        viewHolder.menuName.setText(mData.get(i).getName());
//        viewHolder.menuImage.setText(mData.get(i).getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mData != null) ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView menuName;
        private CircleImageView menuImage;
        private TextView id;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            menuName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvListMenuName);
            menuImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivListMenuImage);
//            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public int getItem(int id) {
        return (mData != null) ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

fragment.java

```
public class DineinFragment extends Fragment implements RecycleParentMenuAdapter.ItemClickListener,RecycleChildMenuAdapter.ItemClickListener, CustomToolbar {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    RecycleParentMenuAdapter storeAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Store> storeArrayList;

    public RecycleChildMenuAdapter menuAdapter;
    public ArrayList<Menu> menuArrayList;

    private TextView toolbarTitle;
    private ImageView btnBackToolbar;

    private TextView titleStore;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public DineinFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static DineinFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        DineinFragment fragment = new DineinFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dinein, container, false);
//        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_store_lists, container, false);
        setCustomToolbar(view);
        addStore();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvStoreList);
        storeAdapter = new RecycleParentMenuAdapter(storeArrayList, getActivity());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        storeAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);

//        titleStore = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvListStoreName);
//        titleStore.setText();

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setCustomToolbar(View view) {
        btnBackToolbar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBackToolbar);
        toolbarTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleToolbar);
        toolbarTitle.setText("Menu");
        btnBackToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.test));
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void addStore() {
        storeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        storeArrayList.add(new Store("1", "Toko A", "www"));
        storeArrayList.add(new Store("2", "Toko B", "www"));
        storeArrayList.add(new Store("3", "Toko C", "www"));
        storeArrayList.add(new Store("4", "Toko D", "www"));
    }

    public void addData() {
        menuArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("1", "Sate Ayam", "Lorem", "www", 13500, "4"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("2", "Ayam Goreng", "Lorem ayam", "www", 17000, "1"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("3", "Sate Kambing", "Lorem sate", "www", 18000, "1"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("4", "Ikan Bakar", "Lorem ikan", "www", 7500, "7"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("5", "Udang Goreng", "Lorem udang", "www", 23350, "2"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("6", "Mie Goreng Aceh", "Lorem mie", "www", 18000, "9"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("7", "Fuyunghai", "Lorem fuyunghai", "www", 25000, "1"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("8", "Nasi Gila", "Lorem Nasi Gila", "www", 16000, "4"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("9", "Rawon Setan", "Lorem rawon", "www", 23000, "3"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("10", "Ayam Tepung", "Lorem ayam tepung", "www", 22000, "6"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("11", "Ikan Tepung", "Lorem ikan tepung", "www", 32000, "8"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("12", "Udang Tepung", "Lorem udang tepung", "www", 37500, "8"));
        menuArrayList.add(new Menu("13", "Cumi Goreng", "Lorem cumi goreng", "www", 32100, "5"));
    }

}
```

StoreModel.java

```
public class Store {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    public Store(String id, String name, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Store() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

MenuModel.java

```
package com.snoci.resto.util.model;
public class Menu {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private String image;
    private Number price;
    private String storeId;

    public Menu(String id, String name, String desc, String image, Number price, String storeId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public Menu() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Number getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Number price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(String storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Make a recyclerview in your parent recycler item layout and set it from the onBind method of  parent recycler

Comment: @VipulChauhan sorry sir, can you explain in more detail. cause i'm really confused. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to populate the RecycleChildAdapter.java in the onBindViewHolder of RecycleParentAdapter.java
like:

```
  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private CircleImageView storeImage;
        private TextView storeName;
        public RecyclerView recycler_view_child;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            storeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivListStoreImage);
            storeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvListStoreName);
            recycler_view_child = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerchild);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

and:

```
public class RecycleParentMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleParentMenuAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Store> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    public RecycleChildAdapter adapter;
```

finally:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.storeName.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
//      holder.storeImage.setImageURI(mData.get(position).getImage());
        LinearLayoutManager manager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        holder.recycler_view_child.setLayoutManager(manager);
        adapter = new ChildAdapter(yourdatalist, context);
        holder.recycler_view_child.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```